# Retrieve database from server via client side

Tags: php, html, mysql, ajax

I am trying to retrive data from another php page for this ia make a ajax , this call post data but gives no reponse plz suggest some idea where i am mistaking.

**Here is my ajax :**

```
    function loadedit(){


      if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
      } else { // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      }
      xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
          document.getElementById("ajaxdiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
      }
      xmlhttp.open("POST","editedit.php",true);
      xmlhttp.send();
    }

    loadedit function will be called on link click.
```

**client.php:**

```
<div class="menuleft">
<a class="menucontent" align="middle" href="http://localhost/DlfIn/home.php">Add</a>
<a class="menucontent" align="middle" onclick="loadedit()">Edit</a>
<a class="menucontent" align="middle" href="http://localhost/DlfIn/home.php">LogOut</a>
</div>
    <div id="ajaxdiv">
    </div>
```

**editedit.php:**

```
    <?php
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
    error_reporting(-1);
    include 'config.php';

        $result = mysqli_query($con,"select * from images");

        //return the array and loop through each row
        if(count($result) > 0){
       echo "<table style='width:300px' border='1'>
    <tr>
      <th></th>
      <th>Title</th>
      <th>Description</th>
      <th>image</th>
      <th>select</th>
    </tr>";
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
         $title=$row['title'];
        $name=$row['name'];
        $id=$row['id'];
        $description=$row['description'];
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td><input type='checkbox' name='checkbox[]' id='checkbox[]' value=".$id."></td>";
        echo "<td><textarea  rows='1' >".$title."</textarea></td>";
        echo "<td><textarea  rows='1' >".$description."</textarea></td>";
        echo "<td><img width='100' height='100' src='images/".$name."'</td>";
        echo "<td><input type='button' id='sub' value='update'></button><input type='button' id='sub' value='delete'></button></td></tr>";
        }
        echo "<tr>
      <td colspan='4' align='center' bgcolor='#FFFFFF'><input name='delete' type='submit' id='sub' value='Delete'></td>
     </tr>
    </table>";  
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: What happens when you load editedit.php directly? I also can't see anything in that code that's looked for posted variables.

Comment: @andrewsi he most likely means he's sending a post request (*`xmlhttp.open("POST","editedit.php",true);`*) to try retrieve the data. Have you tried [`jQuery`](http://www.jquery.com) that has simplified ajax requests?

Comment: @Darren no need to recommend jQuery in this question. It is pretty basic js and the OP has enough issues with coding style as it is (table layout, inline stuff, mixed content, XSS, etc) introducing jQuery will only take the OP further away from solving these issues. Er. Sajal , open your developer tools in your browser and check the network tap. Also check logs.

Comment: i have checked the console and network in it only data got post but in response it returns undefined.

Comment: if i open editedit.php it shows the table with content.